# syntax error while connecting from c# to ms access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am able to read from a MS Access database so I know I have set up my connection string correctly, but I keep getting "syntax error" when I try to insert into that MS Access database. I tried running the same query in Access directly and it works with no errors. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
public void connect()
{
    conn = new OleDbConnection(conn_string);
    conn.Open();
}

public void closeConnection()
{
    conn.Close();
}  

{
    connect();

    // submitQuery = "INSERT INTO TaskSchedular(Grade, Month, Day, Subject, DueDate, AssignmentLink, OrigScore, FinalScore, Task, Priority)  VALUES('8', '17', '10', 'test', '12', 'test', '12', '34', 'test', '2');";

    OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand();
    cmdInsert.Connection = conn;
    cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TaskSchedular(Grade, Month, Day, Subject, DueDate, AssignmentLink, OrigScore, FinalScore, Task, Priority)  VALUES('8', '17', '10', 'test', '12', 'test', '12', '34', 'test', '2');";

    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                
    closeConnection();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    error_msg = ex.Message;
    //MessageBox.Show(error_msg);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include all the [exception details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Comment: It is probably a credential issue.  The connection string could still have a problem.  When it works directly are you using an Admin account?  VS does not automatically run As Admin.  You need to create a shortcut to VS.  Then start VS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng: "It is probably a credential issue" - that seems unlikely, given the report of "syntax error" combined with being able to *read* from the database. (We really need to see the complete exception, ideally with the stack trace. Until then, I think there's relatively little point in guessing.)

Comment: Having said that, I do note that Day and Month are [reserved words for Access custom web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/reserved-words-access-custom-web-app). It's *possible* that that's the problem, but I'm not confident in that until we know more...

Comment: Single quotes around values force number to strings. If database is using a number remove the single quotes.

Comment: @JonSkeet Spot on "It worked" It did occurred to me that I am using reserved words, but it skipped my mind :-( Thank you so much. I was able to insert the records. I am new to stack overflow. Is there a way to mark your answers as correct answer and close this thread

Comment: @TechyTech: Will add an actual *answer* instead of a comment, and then you'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Day` and `Month` are [reserved words](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) in Access, so they need to be enclosed in square brackets. So this part

```
INSERT INTO TaskSchedular(Grade, Month, Day, Subject
```

should be:

```
INSERT INTO TaskSchedular(Grade, [Month], [Day], Subject
```

(There are potentially other issues here, such as specifying numeric values in quotes which probably shouldn't be in quotes, and ideally using parameters instead of putting the values directly in the SQL, but that's slightly separate from this direct question.)